# Request handling in struts and spring. Difference?

Tags: java, spring, struts

Struts 2 Actions are initiated every time when a request is made, whereas in Spring MVC the Controllers are created only once, stored in memory and shared among all the requests.So, Spring Web MVC framework is far efficient to handle the requests than Struts 2.

I have read these sentences in a blog. Though I understand partially, I would like to have a clear understanding on the above. Is the way of handling requests in spring is similar to servlets, where initialization is done only once upon the first request and threads are spawned for every request??? Correspondingly, how this is achieved in struts 2??

Comment: Object instantiation is cheap. In any case, requests get a new action instance--what are you asking? *How*? Using the object factory, which is pluggable.

Comment: refer this useful link --> http://www.cygnet-infotech.com/blog/struts-2-vs-springmvc?bcsi_scan_8d5e706812dbbfea=hV/+NjeMOMyOoIt0gx0POPCWJwQfAAAAzVB2/A==